# $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k^\alpha} >0\quad\text{for all}\ n=1,2,3,\ldots\ \text{and}\ 0<x<\pi, \text{and}\ \alpha \ge 1$

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, special-functions

The [Fejer-Jackson inequality](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1006560422934) as follows:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}k>0\quad\text{for all}\ n=1,2,3,\ldots\ \text{and}\ 0<x<\pi.$$

> I conjecture that the inequality as follows holds:
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{k^\alpha} >0\quad\text{for all}\ n=1,2,3,\ldots\ \text{and}\ 0<x<\pi, \text{and}\ \alpha \ge 1$$
>
> How to prove this inequality? Can You give a comment or a proof or a reference?

Comment: It appears that Theorem A of the following paper solves your problem: https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0898122111008054/1-s2.0-S0898122111008054-main.pdf?_tid=21771cc0-73cc-48ba-afa1-3ae25989a942&acdnat=1530100799_f17da2900208a8df38cfe852dc50b0c9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment by Cherng-tiao Perng converted to an answer: It appears that Theorem A of [this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0898122111008054/1-s2.0-S0898122111008054-main.pdf?_tid=21771cc0-73cc-48ba-afa1-3ae25989a942&acdnat=1530100799_f17da2900208a8df38cfe852dc50b0c9) solves your problem.

Comment: The link to the paper is broken. Could you please write out the title and author? Thank you.

Comment: "On the positivity of certain trigonometric sums and their applications" by Mondal and Swaminathan. [Here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122111008054) is a link to the paper.