# Fejer-Jackson-like inequality with divisor sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, trigonometric-sums

[A question was recently asked](https://mathoverflow.net/q/303759/116087) about a generalization of the Fejer-Jackson inequality $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin kx}{k}\gt 0 \quad \forall\: n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\: \text{and}\: 0\lt x\lt\pi$$

to denominators of the form $k^\alpha$, which a commenter noted is covered by Theorem A of [this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0898122111008054/1-s2.0-S0898122111008054-main.pdf?_tid=21771cc0-73cc-48ba-afa1-3ae25989a942&acdnat=1530100799_f17da2900208a8df38cfe852dc50b0c9).

I wonder, are there other references that can address the apparent positivity of the similar sum where the denominator is replaced by the sum of divisors of $k$, $\sigma(k)$?

> $$\text{Is}\: \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin kx}{\sigma(k)}\gt 0 \quad \forall\: n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\: \text{and}\: 0\lt x\lt\pi\:?$$

Here is what the sum looks like at large $n$ as a function of $x$:

[image]

Can anything else be said about upper or lower bounds in the large $n$ limit?

Thanks.